# Automapper 8.1.1 using reflection not working after update to Abp 4.8.1

Tags: automapper, aspnetboilerplate

I upgraded Abp to 4.8.1. After this update my AutoMapper throws this error:
 - Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

The issue arises when i try to map a DTO to an Entity

Im how im configuring AbpAutomapper

```cs
var thisAssembly = typeof(dsimApplicationModule).GetAssembly();

            IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(thisAssembly);

            Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper().Configurators.Add(
                // Scan the assembly for classes which inherit from AutoMapper.Profile
                cfg => cfg.AddMaps(thisAssembly)


            );
```

My DTO:

```cs
[AutoMapTo(typeof(ServiceTemplate))]
    public class UpdateServiceTemplateDto : EntityDto, IShouldNormalize, ICustomValidate
    {
             //properties
    }
```

In AppService, Update Method:

```cs
var serviceTemplate = ObjectMapper.Map<ServiceTemplate>(input);
```

Worked fine before update. I Read that dynamic mapping is depricated in Automapper 8.1.1. Not sure this is considered dynamic though since i use reflection.

Comment: It is dynamic. If you don't want to do what the message says, just use 8.1.0.

Comment: Create a repro project on GitHub that is forked from [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template).